# Symfony: get new ID in a form

Tags: forms, symfony, key, creation

I have an object displaying within a form, a hidden field being related to its PK (field id). 
When I create a new object, the field has a null value. Submitting the form, the object is inserted into the DB and it now has an ID, but the field in the page still has a null value. 
If a reload the page, now the ID is indeed set in the hidden field.

In my opinion, this is due to the form processing of Symfony: when a create an object, it creates a form, with this form valid the object is saved but the form still uses the data before it was saved.

The question is: how to get the auto-incremented key in the form up-to-date? Shouldn't the form only have a reference to the object? Can't the value be updated?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 1):

make sur that you call `$entityManager->flush()` method after insert and that you bind your form whene you have same data in your request object

`$form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));`

Answer (score 0):

You should have an `Entity` assigned to your `Form` by `FormFactory`. Then Symfony will fill that Entity with submitted values. What's left is only persist the Entity and flush to database.

You can find steb-by-step form submission in Symfony [Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)

Comment: Maybe it is slightly different for me, as I use Propel and not Doctrine? As I understand it from documentation, we should always redirect the user if the form is valid. But what to do if form is valid but saving throws an sql exception?

Comment: What kind of Exception is thrown? If it's related with uniquenes or something - You can flush() (save in db) inside of try - catch block.

Comment: I have no exception. My problem is that I have form field related to the primary key, but creating a new object the displayed field is not updated with the auto-incremented value and it stays null, where it has a value if I reload the object

Comment: Maybe You call `$form->createView()` before You `flush()` form object to database? This way Your ID gets populated after the view is created. At least this how it works in Doctrine...